Physics Principle of Balancing Board
Consider one of these

Typically, it is well known that having you legs further apart helps you balance better, the wider the base, the easier it is to balance. I guess a  body with a larger base area will have the line through its centre of gravity passing through its base even when tilted through a larger angle making it more stable.
How do we explain why having your feet apart is actually more stable? Is my above statement correct? Can we explain this idea in depth?
Now coming back to the balance board. Whilst doing exercise, I found that having my two feet as close together as possible actually made me more stable. To me, this seems counterintuitive given the statement above. Hence, what is making this foot positioning more stable?
Edit: Looking for depth physics explanations to help me understand both my questions.

The feet apart -> stability argument is the same as with the usual ones. However, on top of the balancing board, no matter where your foot are, the actual area in contact is the one at the bottom, the calculation is totally something else. So that if you stood with your feet together, it would be less likely to accidentally tip things either way. You are just supposed to mathematically analyse the problem yourself.

Whilst doing exercise, I found that having my two feet as close together as possible actually made me more stable.
The opposite for me as I do not want the line of action of my weight from my centre of mass to fall outside the region between my two feet.
How do we explain why having your feet apart is actually more stable?
In some ways when you are standing on your board you are walking a tightrope.
In this case you need the line of action of your weight from your centre of mass to pass through the "point" of contact between board and floor which is much more difficult than just standing on the floor.
To move your centre of mass you need to rotate your body about the point of contact by applying a torque which will cause an angular acceleration given by the rotational equivalent of Newton's second law, $\text{torque = moment of inertia } \times \text{ angular acceleration}$.
Think about what you do to have more control, spread your legs and your arms (tightrope walker - long pole) which increases the moment of inertia so the same torque will produce a smaller angular acceleration, ie you will have more control, or put another way to get the same angular acceleration you will need to apply more torque again having more control.
As well as that you can correct the wrong movement by moving you body, including your arms in the opposite direction to the rotation of the board.

Actually the moment of inertia will increase quadratically with the distance of the rotating mass from the rotation center, which is the contact point of the board to the ground. So I doubt, that spreading your legs, which will make you smaller overall, i.e. move your center of mass closer to the center of rotation will increase the moment of inertia.

@Zaph So you are suggesting that lowering the centre of mass increases the stability?

No, I do suggest, that the increased stability comes from other sources then increased moment of inertia. I would guess, that just shifting around to adept is easier to coordinate intuitively, when you can shift your weight between 2 points with larger distance, and therefore feels more stable. If once model of the human would just be a rigid body, I do indeed believe he would fall over faster with spread legs then when staying tall.
